# Using Bloom AI Model on Mac M1 for continuing prompts (Pytorch)

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, apple-m1, metal, huggingface-transformers

I try to run the bigscience Bloom AI Model on my Macbook M1 Max 64GB, freshly installed pytorch for Mac M1 chips and Python 3.10.6 running.
I'm not able to get any output at all.
With other AI Models I have the same issue and I really don't know how I should fix it.

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

device = "mps" if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else "cpu"
if device == "cpu" and torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = "cuda" #if the device is cpu and cuda is available, set the device to cuda
print(f"Using {device} device") #print the device

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bigscience/bloom")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("bigscience/bloom").to(device)

input_text = "translate English to German: How old are you?"
input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids.to(device)

outputs = model.generate(input_ids)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0]))
```

I've tried it with other Models (smaller bert Models) and also tried letting it just run on CPU without using the mps device at all.

Maybe anyone could help

Comment: If it is important: I'm using 113.0 Beta (22A5352e), but that should't be a problem I guess

Answer (score 0):

It might be taking too long to get the output. Do you want to break it down to serial calls involving
a) embedding layer b) the 70 bloom blocks c) then the output layer norm and d) the token decoding?

An example to run this code is available at https://nbviewer.org/urls/arteagac.github.io/blog/bloom_local.ipynb .

It basically boils down to:

```
def forward(input_ids):
    # 1. Create attention mask and position encodings
    attention_mask = torch.ones(len(input_ids)).unsqueeze(0).bfloat16().to(device)
    alibi = build_alibi_tensor(input_ids.shape[1], config.num_attention_heads,
                               torch.bfloat16).to(device)
    # 2. Load and use word embeddings
    embeddings, lnorm = load_embeddings()
    hidden_states = lnorm(embeddings(input_ids))
    del embeddings, lnorm

    # 3. Load and use the BLOOM blocks sequentially
    for block_num in range(70):
        load_block(block, block_num)
        hidden_states = block(hidden_states, attention_mask=attention_mask, alibi=alibi)[0]
        print(".", end='')
    
    hidden_states = final_lnorm(hidden_states)
    
    #4. Load and use language model head
    lm_head = load_causal_lm_head()
    logits = lm_head(hidden_states)

    # 5. Compute next token 
    return torch.argmax(logits[:, -1, :], dim=-1)
```

Please refer the linked notebook to get the implementation for functions used in the `forward` call.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. Also other Larger Language Models seem to have the same problem. 
But now I know what happens, but I have no idea to solve it.
By running the code it only fills up the RAM and after that it fills up the SWAP and after this one is completely filled up the programm just crashes.

I tried it with the new language model of facebook (Galactica) and it had the same problem as the Bloom Model has

Comment: I also implemented the CPU as a fallback method and for small Language Models that seem to work, but if just mps is used it collapse the way I told in the comment before

Comment: @ZeroToHero are you having the same problem with smaller models like GPT-2 or even BERT type of models? Models with that size shouldn't require more than 8 GB of RAM to run them